# Test if all elements of a Foldable are the same

Tags: haskell

I built a function that verifies that all elements of a foldable structure are equal.

Compared to a similar function on the lists, it seems to me that the more general function is disproportionately complex, but I have not been able to simplify it.

Do you have any suggestions?

```
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Sequence as SQ
import Data.Matrix as MT

allElementsEqualL :: Eq a => [a] -> Bool
allElementsEqualL [] = True
allElementsEqualL (x:ns) = all (== x) ns
-- allElementsEqualL [1,1,1] -> True

allElementsEqualF :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => t a -> Bool
allElementsEqualF xs = case (getFirst . foldMap (First . Just) $ xs) of
                        Nothing -> True
                        Just x  -> all (== x) xs

-- allElementsEqualF [1,1,1] -> True

-- allElementsEqualF $ SQ.fromList [1,1,1] -> True

-- allElementsEqualF $ MT.fromLists [[1,1],[1,1]] -> True
```

Comment: Of course, you can always do `allElementsEqualF = allElementsEqualL . toList`.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I recently thought of this solution, but I thought it could be very expensive from the point of view of conversion between types. If instead everything happened in a "lazy" way, maybe it would be the most convenient and fastest solution. Is it correct?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov I thought also a mixed solution: allElementsEqualF2 xs
  -- | F.null xs = True
  -- | otherwise = all (== x) xs
    -- where
    -- x = head $ F.toList xs     --- so if goList is lazy, the test is carried out upon the original type (with all).

Comment: I decided it was worth a separate answer after all :)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know about less complicated, but I think this is the "cleanest" way to do it. By "clean," I mean it's one traversal over the structure using a single, special `Monoid`.

```
data Same a = Vacuous | Fail | Same a
instance Eq a => Semigroup (Same a) where
    Vacuous    <> x       = x
    Fail       <> _       = Fail
    s@(Same l) <> Same r  = if l == r then s else Fail
    x          <> Vacuous = x
    _          <> Fail    = Fail
instance Eq a => Monoid (Same a) where
    mempty = Vacuous

allEq :: (Foldable f, Eq a) => f a -> Bool
allEq xs = case foldMap Same xs of
                Fail -> False
                _    -> True
```

Comment: I think `Same` is isomorphic to `Success a` from the [zero](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/zero-0.1.4/docs/Data-Zero.html) package.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs I kind of doubt it. `Same a` has two extra constructors compared to `a`, whereas `Success a` has just one. Now it might be `Success (Maybe a)` or something... but at that point I would say having a custom type is more readable.

Comment: It is, however, true that `Zero (Same a)` with `zero = Fail`.

Comment: `Same a` has `n + 2` elements. `Success a` *is* `Maybe (Maybe a)`, which also has `n + 2` elements. (Ignoring bottoms.)

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Hm. When I follow your link, I see `newtype Success a = Success { getSuccess :: Maybe a }`, which has just one `Maybe` wrapper, not two.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Whoops! You do need to track the elements plus one extra bit of information (whether you've seen an element and failed to match, or whether you've just not seen an element yet.) So the structure you're looking for should have `n + 2` elements.

Comment: I love those bring-your-own-monoid solutions :)

Comment: @HTNW I appreciate your solution. I would like to ask you a question that is a little off the subject. The Same semigroup is commutative; Given this, is there a way to indicate this property and to make Haskell (or GHC) automatically expand the symmetrical part?

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Do you want a catch-all equation `x <> y = y <> x`?

Comment: @HTNW Yes, it would be fine. Ex. ::Com (Vacuous  <> x  = x) should be interpreted (expanded) (by GHC?) as: Vacuous  <> x  = x;   x <> Vacuous = x.

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani No, I mean you can literally replace the last two equations with `x <> y = y <> x` and have it work, right?

Comment: @HTNW Why if I replace the two Vacuous occurences in (Semigroup(Same)'s instance  with 1 line: "Vacuous  <> x  =  x <> Vacuous" the compiler give me an error? ("Non-exhaustive patterns in function <>")

Comment: @AlbertoCapitani Because the patterns aren't exhaustive if you write it like that? This is not something you can be clever with. The LHSs need to cover all patterns, period, no matter what the RHSs are. You can write `Vacuous <> x = x; Fail <> x = Fail; s@(Same l) <> Same r  = if l == r then s else Fail; x <> y = y <> x` if you want to show commutativity. That's the best I can think up.

Comment: @HTNW Thank you very much.

Comment: One issue with this is that `allEqTo $ 2 : (cycle [1])` does not terminate - a rather exotic case, though.

Answer (score 7):

The convenient thing about your first function that doesn't exist in your second is that we have a convenient way of getting the "head" of a list. Fortunately, we can do the same for a `Foldable`. Let's write a `head'` that works on any `Foldable` (and for the sake of type safety we'll have our `head'` return a `Maybe`)

```
head' :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => t a -> Maybe a
head' = foldr (\a _ -> Just a) Nothing
```

Now we can write basically the same code as the list case for the general one.

```
allElementsEqualF :: (Foldable t, Eq a) => t a -> Bool
allElementsEqualF f = case head' f of
                        Nothing -> True
                        Just a -> all (== a) f
```

Syntactically, it looks different, but it's the exact same thing you did in your list case: check if the structure is empty and, if it's not, then see if every element is equal to the first.

Note that, technically, this is not *quite* equivalent to the code you posted, as it compares the first element against itself. So if your `==` operator is for some reason not reflexive, you'll get different results (try running my code and yours on the list `[read "NaN" :: Double]`)

Answer (score 6):

Silvio's answer is syntactically small and easy to understand; however, it may do extra work associated with doing two folds if the `Foldable` instance can't compute `head'` cheaply. In this answer I will discuss how to perform the calculation in just one pass whether the underlying `Foldable` can compute `head'` cheaply or not.

The basic idea is this: instead of tracking just "are all the elements equal so far", we'll also track what they're all equal to. So:

```
data AreTheyEqual a
    = Empty
    | Equal a
    | Inequal
    deriving Eq
```

This is a `Monoid`, with `Empty` as the unit and `Inequal` as an absorbing element.

```
instance Eq a => Semigroup (AreTheyEqual a) where
    Empty <> x = x
    x <> Empty = x
    Equal a <> Equal b | a == b = Equal a
    _ <> _ = Inequal

instance Eq a => Monoid (AreTheyEqual a) where
    mempty = Empty
```

Now we can use `foldMap` to summarize an entire `Foldable`, like so:

```
allElementsEqual :: (Eq a, Foldable f) => f a -> Bool
allElementsEqual = (Inequal /=) . foldMap Equal
```

Comment: I think this is the same as my answer?

Comment: @HTNW Yep! Seems we overlapped in answering.

Comment: It doesn't necessarily do two traversals. For structures where `foldr` can implement guarded recursion, it may only look at the top-most constructor the first time.

Comment: @ReinHenrichs Good point. I'll amend my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 4):

A rather trivial option, and I would generally prefer one of the other answers, is reusing `allElementsEqualL`:

```
allElementsEqualF = allElementsEqualL . toList
```

or after inlining

```
allElementsEqualF xs = case toList xs of
                         [] -> True
                         x:xs' -> all (== x) xs'
```

It's laziness which makes it reasonable. The `all` call doesn't demand the entire `xs'`, but only until it finds the first one different from `x`. So `toList` will also not demand the entire `xs`. And at the same time, already examined elements don't need to be kept in memory.

You could write a `Foldable` instance for which `toList` is less lazy than necessary, but except for those cases I think it should do exactly as much work as Daniel Wagner's and HTNW's answer (with slight overhead not depending on input size).

> I thought also a mixed solution:
>
> ```
> allElementsEqualF2 xs | F.null xs = True 
>                       | otherwise = all (== x) xs 
>     where x = head $ F.toList xs
> ```
>
> so if goList is lazy, the test is carried out upon the original type (with all).

This does slightly more work in the non-empty case than Silvio's answer, because `F.null` duplicates exactly as much of `F.toList`'s work as `head'` does. So Silvio's code has to get to the first element 2 times (one for `head'` and another inside `all`), and yours does it 3 times (`null`, `head $ toList xs` and `all` again).

Comment: There are types (such as snoc-lists, or any other type with heavily left-biased trees) where this will do significantly more work than HTNW's and my solution.

Comment: I considered them, but thought it ends up being the same because foldMap is still required to iterate over them in order and can't take advantage of your monoids being commutative. No?

Comment: Hmmm. The answer is... trickier than I was thinking it was before. `foldMap` may iterate in any order it likes (because monoids are required to be associative), but the implementation of `mappend` and in particular which order it forces its arguments in may affect how many elements are actually "visited". Reviewing my and HTNW's answer, both our `mappend` implementations are strict in their first argument, which probably forces all the work to be done left-to-right. Rats! Okay, I no longer endorse my previous comment.