# Check all characters are the same in a string

Tags: algorithm, debugging, haskell

Was wondering if you could help me, I'm writing a haskell program and im using the transpose method and its working as I wish. But I then wish to check each [string] returned from the transpose is of the same charcter e.g

```
transpose["hello","help","hell","helm"]
```

would return something like

```
["hhhh","eeee","llll","plml","o"]
```

I wonder is it then possible to go through each the above and stopping when the string isn't of all the same characters e.g stoping at "plml"

Comment: Sounds like you should be using [takeWhile](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:takeWhile). I'll leave you to come up with a suitable predicate function (which you could for example write with a fairly simple direct recursion).

Comment: Could this then be essentially used to get the longest common prefix?

Comment: Is something like autocompletion, you start enter a world and you have a list of words start with same letters ?

Comment: It’s a longest common prefix problem I’m trying to perform

Comment: Give this a try `takeWhile ((==1) . length . nub)`. Sorry for the curt comment, I'm in a lecture ;)

Comment: @MikaelF `nub` is needlessly expensive if all you want to know is that there's exactly one element. You could instead use `all` to test whether each element of the list is equal to the list's first element.

Comment: @amalloy so how do you mean to go about it? Still use a takeWhile?

Comment: Related: [Test if all elements of a Foldable are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55815807/7509065)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way of doing it is to apply `group` to each string:

```
> group "hhhh"
["hhhh"]
> group "plml"
["p","l","m","l"]
```

Then, if you `takeWhile` the group count is 1, you'll get all the homogeneous strings:

```
> test = ["hello","help","hell","helm"]
> import Data.List
> takeWhile ((==1) . length) . map group . transpose $ test
[["hhhh"],["eeee"],["llll"]]
```

You can get rid of the extra list layer with `map head`.

Also, it would actually be better to replace this test for single groups with a custom pattern match function:

```
single :: [a] -> Bool
single [a] = True
single _ = False
```

and use:

```
> map head . takeWhile single . map group . transpose $ test
["hhhh","eeee","llll"]]
```

The main difference is that `(==1) . length` needs to evaluate and count the length of the whole set of groups, but `single` can stop early.  For example, on an infinite string:

```
> ((==1) . length) $ group $ "aaa" ++ repeat 'b'  -- hangs forever
> single $ group $ "aaa" ++ repeat 'b'  -- returns `False` at first 'b'
```

An alternative, suggested in the comments, would be to do a more direct check that the first character is equal to all the other characters:

```
allSame :: (Eq a) => [a] -> Bool
allSame (x:rest) = all (==x) rest
```

and:

```
> takeWhile allSame . transpose $ test
["hhhh","eeee","llll"]
```

**SPOILERS:** 
As per your comments, you're trying to find the longest prefix, so to finish things off, note that you want to `map head` across:

```
["hhhh","eeee","llll"]
```

to get:

```
['h','e','l']
```

which is the same as:

```
"hel"
```

Since `map head` followed by `map head` can be written `map head . map head`, or even shorter `map (head . head)`, the final definition using `group` can be written:

```
prefix :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
prefix = map (head . head) . takeWhile single . map group . transpose
   where single [a] = True
         single _ = False
```

and the final definition using `allSame` can be written:

```
prefix :: (Eq a) => [[a]] -> [a]
prefix = map head . takeWhile allSame . transpose
   where allSame (x:rest) = all (==x) rest
```

Comment: Amazing! thank you so much. If you don't mind could you possibly give a quick breakdown of the line 'prefix = map (head . head) . takeWhile single . map group . transpose' as in how it works on the string